# Fix outbound migration notice when a question is migrated to Stack Overflow en español

Tags: feature-request, migration, international-sites, migration-notice

[This question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/36882/no-muestra-correctamente-el-contenido-del-fichero-dependiendo-de-la-palabra?noredirect=1) was recently migrated from Spanish.SE to Stack Overflow en español. The migration notice in the **outbound** question (accessible with the URL option `noredirect=1`, or seemingly also accessible by default without that option to Spanish.SE moderators) says:

> This question was migrated to Stack Overflow en español so that it can be answered in the desired language.

It turns out that migrations from Spanish.SE to Stack Overflow en español (which do happen once in a while) are not done "so that the question can be answered in the desired language", as both sites allow answers in Spanish. These migrations happen because the question is about programming instead of about the Spanish language. I guess also that migrations from (any site other than Stack Overflow) to Stack Overflow en español are not necessarily done only for the reason stated in the migration notice.

Can the migration notice be updated to be similar to the standard message for inbound migrations? Something like

> This question was migrated to Stack Overflow en español because it can be answered there.

Answer (score 2):

(Note: you need access to 10K tools in the source sites to see the example posts I am referring to, since they are deleted posts)

This seems to be a default sentence when migrated questions involve an international Stack Overflow site.

See examples:

- Spanish.SE → SOes ([example](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/36882/no-muestra-correctamente-el-contenido-del-fichero-dependiendo-de-la-palabra?noredirect=1), the one you mention in the question)

> This question was migrated to Stack Overflow en español so that it can be answered in the desired language.

- SOes → SOpt ([example](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/118210/dados-desaparecem-ao-mover-scroll-recyclerview-com-firebase?noredirect=1))

> This question was migrated to Stack Overflow em Português so that it can be answered in the desired language.

- SOes → Spanish.SE ([example](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/44402/qu%C3%A9-significa-stacks?noredirect=1))

> This question was migrated to Spanish Language Stack Exchange so that it can be answered in the desired language.

- SOes → SO ([example](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18523/why-my-program-dont-recognize-the-txt-file?noredirect=1))

> This question was migrated to Stack Overflow so that it can be answered in the desired language.

- SO → SOes ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61006299/jsp-no-puede-recuperar-los-atributos-seteados-en-el-servlet?noredirect=1))

> This question was migrated to Stack Overflow en español so that it can be answered in the desired language.

In fact, this very sentence [appears in Transifex](https://es.traducir.win/strings/15950) as:

> `Original String:  This question was migrated to [$toSiteName$]($destinationUrl$) so that it can be answered in the desired language.`

There [is another, generic one](https://es.traducir.win/strings/15379), that says:

> `Original String:  This question was migrated to [$toSiteName$]($destinationUrl$) because it can be answered by $destinationSiteAudience$.`

This one does have a translation, while the previous one doesn't, so the former seems to be a new way to explaining it, that clearly fails for cases when the migration is not among SOxx sites.